# Make sure that each highststock grouping is same count

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to chart Intraday  Volume chart (Column chart), but i am having problem with the highstock grouping strategy, it's distribute the groups using time regardless how many points is each group, as a result, it is using a column for each hour, and Market is opening in 09:30 (NY time). this yield to have short columns for first hour since it's only 30 points.

Attached snapshot

[image]

Comment: Hi @Akram Kamal Qassas, Could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zuywrp3c/

Comment: Working example: 

    http://jsfiddle.net/d8roL7g6/

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible. The only solution that I can see is to preprocess your data and apply custom data grouping.